# Why is it "die Hausschuhe stehen and not liegen unter dem Bett"?

Tags: difference

Why is it "die Hausschuhe **stehen** and not **liegen** unter dem Bett"?

Answer (score 15):

If shoes are placed in the same way they would be worn, i.e. on the sole, they are considerd standing (at least in German). If you say *die Schuhe liegen*, one would assume that they are lying on the side, upside down or in an unordered heap.

Comment: I would have used *liegen* for every other position, especially as an untidy heap, or if kicked under the bed from the other side of the room.

Comment: @guidot You are right, I modified my answer

Comment: Yes, in my feeling of the language "stehen" is the result of "stellen", i.e. intentionally placing them, while "liegen" is the result of just dicovering they are there (if you kick them to the side, they would "liegen", not "stehen" (dispite of the fact that boots actually would no longer stand then).

Answer (score 2):

boots are taller than wide. This was perceived as standing up rather than lying down. It must have become grammaticalized and generalized.

Part of it is that we stand in and on shoes, as @VolkerLandgraf implied. Standing, and walking by extension, is the inherent purpose of feet equipment.

This applies to most set-ups that have a preffered standard orientation, like cups, except if notably two dimensional or amorph, and not to objects that tend to be moved or rather move on their own, like ships or dice. (Hence the joke about the running fridge, because it can run and stand at the same time).

In principle there's nothing wrong about *liegen* in this context, anyhow. In most cases a simple *sein* does the job as well.

Answer (score -4):

It depends on the shape of the specific "Hausschuhe". If you are talking about "Pantoffeln"
('slippers'), which are flat, one would rather use "liegen"...

Comment: No, if they are on the sole, it's always '_stehen_'. All objects that have a definded bottom made for being in contact with the place they are posed on, '_stehen_'. So, plates 'stand', because they have a circular 'foot' on the underside. But you can also arrange them vertically like in a dishwasher, then, in German, you call this also '_(senkrecht) stellen / stehen_': _Die Teller stehen hochkant im Tellerregal_. _Hausschuhe 'liegen'_ entweder _auf der Seite_ oder _mit der Sohle nach oben_, vielleicht auch _übereinander_. Das ist assoziiert mit '_unaufgeräumt, unordentlich_'.

Comment: @RalfJoerres. Thanks for your replay with which I partially disagree. Before embarking on what I hope could be a constructive discussion, I'd like to know from what perspective you are arguing. If it is a normative one along the lines of"right/wrong", no need for further discussion. If it's a descriptive one (what people say and what current language looks like), I'll be very happy to develop our exchange.

Comment: A short hint for reflection: "Wo stehen meine Flippflopps"???

Comment: @Nico, also meine Flippflopps stehen im Schuhschrank.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Sorry for the typo. I meant "Flip-Flops".

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Sorry for the typo. I meant "Flip-Flops". Yous maybe, but not everyone's: https://www.alamy.de/flip-flops-liegen-am-strand-unter-rosa-schwimmen-kreis-sommer-urlaub-konzept-die-sonne-scheint-hell-schneiden-image240404514.html                                                                                                                  For reason of space I can only post this link as a little "Vorgeschmack" ;-)

Comment: @Nico: I'm not normative. I'm looking and listening to language and trying to find out regularities. The problem for me as a German teacher is, that I have to explain when you have to say that '_ein Buch liegt_' or '_es steht_'; '_ich stelle / setze die Tasse ab_', '_die Katze steht_' or '_sie sitzt am Fenster_'. Why '_das Frühstücksbrettchen liegt_' but '_der Teller steht auf dem Tisch_'? Why '_die Maus liegt gut in der Hand_' but '_die Tür sitzt schief_'? ... "Flip-Flops liegen am Strand unter Rosa schwimmen Kreis" is not German, perhaps it's computer generated tagging.

Comment: @Ralf. Das sollte keine Provokation sein. Ich argumentiere als Linguist und der Kern meiner Aussage war, dass "liegen" mittlerweile ziemlich häufig in Bezug auf flaches Schuhwerk gebraucht wird. Wenn du eine Google-Suche mit "liegen" in Kombination mit "Pantoffeln", Sandalen etc. durchführst, wirst du zahlreiche Attestierungen in deutschen Zeitungen, Romanen und gepflegten Konversationen finden. Diese Fälle indizieren weder Unordnung noch verdrehte Lage. Das gepostete Beispiel war zugegebenermaßen daneben. Dieses Phänomen lässt sich gut durch Lakoffs Prototypentheorie erklären. Rest folgt.

Comment: @Nico: Im Ernst, _Pantoffeln liegen im Regal, schön ordentlich hingelegt_? Ich hab kurz gekuckt, die Fälle bei Google sind alle ein bisschen anders. Aber kann schon sein, dass sich da ein Sprachgebrauch eingestellt hat, den ich nicht mitbekommen habe, nur: Bei Pantoffeln/Sandalen/Flipflops finde ich das nicht so wichtig. Gibt's da ähnliche Fälle, steckt da ein System dahinter? Bei dem Foto mit dem verkorksten Text war mein erster Gedanke: Ja, das Zeug hat jemand da hingeworfen und das liegt jetzt eben da rum, die Badelatschen zufällig auf der Sohle.

Comment: Andersrum würde man sagen: _Ich habe die Schuhe in den Koffer gelegt_ (bzw. sowieso 'gepackt') auch wenn sie da vielleicht erst mal auf der Sohle stehen. _Ich hab die Mokassins auf die schwarzen Lederschuhe gelegt_ - mag gehen, vielleicht auch weil sie sehr leicht sind, das scheint neben allem anderen auch eine Rolle zu spielen. Kommt mir aber ein bisschen zu speziell vor. Unterschiedliche Raumkonzepte in den Sprachen sind allerdings ziemlich wichtig.

Comment: @RalfJoerres. Hier ein Beispiel, das mir fundiert erscheint: https://books.google.de/books?id=QZ99DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT44&lpg=PT44&dq=%22pantoffeln+lagen%22&source=bl&ots=LAtLiuQRVt&sig=ACfU3U0BjGg08T_j3qDXDoawvj0TQeOHRQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvgLK9sKnnAhUyuqQKHT5-A2QQ6AEwD3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22pantoffeln%20lagen%22&f=false Ich vermute mal, dass das "System" darin liegt, dass manche Sprecher die flache Form von gewissen Schuhen mit ebenso flachen Gegenständen assoziieren, die "liegen" erfordern, und aus dem Grund das Verb per Analogie projizieren. Ja, der Text war pures Gedöns.Grüße von W nach E!

Comment: Deine Antwort auf die Eingangsfrage war vollkommen angemessen. Ich bin ja derjenige gewesen, der Teufels Advokat gespielt hat ...

Comment: @Nico: Stimmt, das Beispiel kommt hin. Dazu könnte man auch wieder einiges sagen von wegen bemühtem Stil, aber das lassen wir jetzt mal schön bleiben. In meinem Leben spielt wohl insgesamt das Liegen oder Stehen von Pantoffeln und ähnlichem keine Rolle und bietet für mich keinen Sprechanlass.

Comment: Is auch juut so!

Comment: @RalfJoerres "All objects that have a definded bottom made for being in contact with the place they are posed on, 'stehen'.". I just got a new matress. And the new matress "liegt" on my bed. A matress that is "stehend" would be one which *is not* in the position that is primarily intended to be in, e.g. standing on a cart in a furniture store, for transport.

Comment: @Polygnome: Okay, I confess: _Matratzen, Teppiche, Fußmatten, Lattenroste, Tagesdecken_ and similar objects '_liegen_' in cases of proper use, so do '_Gehwegplatten_' and '_Pflastersteine_' as toppings of roadways and footpaths, as well as '_Tischdecken_' and '_Platzdeckchen_' on tables, '_Mausmatten_' on desks, maybe because they are perceived as surfaces. Perhaps one would say '_auf dem Tisch stand ein zugeklapptes Notebook_', but '_lag ein zugeklapptes Notebook mit der Unterseite nach oben_' - that's the point I had in mind when I was talking about a 'defined bottom'.